# How to edit the text area, font and password mask in a R Shiny shinyauthr login page

Tags: r, shiny, shinyauthr

How to edit the text area, font and password mask in a R Shiny shinyauthr login page

How can 1) the text area, 2) font and 3) password mask colours, be edited in a R Shiny shinyauthr login page please? I am keen to explore ‘inline’ style editing options if possible.

The sample code below is lifted directly from ‘https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyauthr/man/loginUI.html’; my real code is running with a bs4dash dashboard and the login fields are inheriting a dark background with dark font and password mask.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)

user_base <- dplyr::tibble(
  user = c("user1", "user2"),
  password = c("pass1", "pass2"),
  permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
  name = c("User One", "User Two")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(class = "pull-right", shinyauthr::logoutUI(id = "logout")),
  shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login"),
  tableOutput("user_table")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  credentials <- shinyauthr::loginServer(
    id = "login",
    data = user_base,
    user_col = user,
    pwd_col = password,
    log_out = reactive(logout_init())
  )

  logout_init <- shinyauthr::logoutServer(
    id = "logout",
    active = reactive(credentials()$user_auth)
  )

  output$user_table <- renderTable({
    req(credentials()$user_auth)
    credentials()$info
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `shinyauthr` doesn't apply any helpful CSS classes to the generated login panel, so you'll need to make your own to be able to select the elements of interest. I'd probably wrap the `loginUI` in a div, and then target the `input` elements within that div.

A bare-bones example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyauthr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(".login-ui input { color: #fff; background: tomato }"),
  div(class = "login-ui", shinyauthr::loginUI(id = "login")),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  shinyauthr::loginServer("login", data = data.frame())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: login panel with red background and white text]

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for.